# Preventing cache of swf using Java

Tags: java, caching, servlets, flash

I want to load the swf everytime its changed.
I have written a class which returns path with modified time.

I am loading the swf using Loader in flex.

```
public class CacheBustingService {
    public static String getTimeStamp(String inPath)
    {
        File file = new File(inPath);
        String modified = file.lastModified()+"";
        return modified+inPath;
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding modified time in query string like: inPath?modifiedTime=modified 
Its not working.
Can anybody suggest me better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Filter that is mapped to `*.swf` and adds `Expires: -1`, and other cache-preventing headers.

Comment: Can you be more specific?, I didnt understand the solution.

Comment: which part? You don't know how to create a Filter; you don't want how to map it, or you don't know the cache headers?

Comment: The url which is getting generated using this class is sent back to the as3 using xml. In this case i dont think so filters and cache-preventing headers will be helpful.  In jsp i am using this class like this:           <Swf>
            <% out.print(CacheBustingService.getTimeStamp("/Project/assets/swf/test.swf"));%>
          </Swf>